# Geodesics on Cone with new Metric and Law.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, geodesic

On a surface of revolution using cylindrical coordinates $r,z $ primed with respect to $ \theta $ how to trace geodesics on a cone $ r= z \tan \gamma \; $  with metric

$$ \; ds= \sqrt{r^2-r^{'2}+z^{'2}}\; d\theta\; ?\; \tag1 $$

Using Euler-Lagrange equation on above metric  with cone $z'= r'\cot\gamma$ we obtain a *new geodesic definition:*

$$  r. \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-r^{'2}+z^{'2}}}=c \tag2 $$

To solve this

$$ \frac{r^4}{c^2}= r^2-r^{'2}+z^{'2} $$

$$ \int \dfrac{dr}{r\sqrt{1-\dfrac{r^2}{c^2}}} =\dfrac{\theta}{ (1-\cot^2\gamma) } \tag3 $$

With $\theta$ parameter integrates to :

$$\tanh\frac{r(\theta)}{2c}=\tan\frac{\theta}{2\sqrt{1-\cot^2 \gamma}}; z(\theta ) = r(\theta)\cot\gamma \tag4 $$

[image]

Background how it was obtained:

With Euclidean metric $ds= \sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}+z^{'2}}\; $ and Euler-Lagrange with Beltrami special relation ( not dependent on $\theta$)

$$ \sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}+z^{'2}}- r'\frac{r'}{\sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}+z^{'2}}}-z'\frac{z'}{\sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}+z^{'2}}}= r. \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+r^{'2}+z^{'2}}}=c $$

that simplifies to:

$$ r\cdot \sin \psi = c$$

which is the Clairaut relation.

Your comments will be most appreciated in finding a ***geometric interpretation*** of this length invariant $c$ in this  research effort. Shown blue rings have radius $c$.

As is known in  elliptic geometry the invariant $c$ represents the Clairaut minimum radial distance of geodesic to axis of symmetry.

Comment: Apologies about error before edit. Perhaps there may be a connection to hyperbolic geometry and relativity..